# How was Takuto be able to become a shinigami if he was in a coma?

Tags: full-moon-wo-sagashite

In *Full Moon wo Sagashite*, Takuto became a shinigami because he committed suicide, but in the end, he was actually in a coma.

How was he be able to become a shinigami if he was just in a coma?

Answer (score 1):

Takuto was only a "shinigami in training" rather than a full shinigami. It is never explicitly said, but I think it is safe to conclude that he was never a full shinigami because he was never dead, but because his near-death condition was caused by an attempt at suicide, he was very near to becoming a true shinigami, hence, "shinigami in training."